# How to find this holomorphic function if the points explode?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a holomorphic function in the neighborhood of $0$ such that its value in the point $\frac 1n$ is $(-1)^n\frac 1{n^3}$.

Unfortunely we don't have more hypothesis than this, so I first took $n\in \Bbb R$ to see what happend, however I belive that even if $n$ is complex the images and preimages behave similar, althought I don't understand well what are we suppose to be seeing with this exercise.

I'm a little baffled because if $f$ is the function we are looking for, around $0$ happens that $\frac 1n\to \infty$ so$f(\frac 1n)=(-1)^n\frac 1{n^3}\to \infty$, and even more it explodes more wildly than $\frac 1n$. I don't know how to start building this holomorphic $f$ around $0$ if it explodes so bad. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n \frac 1 {n^3} = 0$. $n \to \infty$ means $\frac {1} {n} \to 0$.

Comment: The problem doesn't say the function is *entire*.  It only needs to be defined near $0$, not at $0$

Comment: @hife Yes I know, but I consider $n\to 0$ not $n\to \infty$, was that wrong?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok, but the problem does says that $f$ should be holomorphic in a neighborhood around $0$, so we can make it very small, can we take it without $0$?

Comment: @WillJagy: Oh dear...right you are. Too late at night to be doing math....

Comment: @WillJagy We are not following a book, but rather notes from another teacher's class. However the tutor refers to Ahlfors' book quite often.

Comment: @AnaGalois: The function is defined in a neighbourhood of $0$, so $1/n$ has to be close to zero, so $n$ has to be big. Even then, if $n \to 0$, $1/n \to \infty$, so the function would only explode at $\infty$, which is not a problem. The actual contradiction is what mrf wrote, using the identity theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be no such function.

Assume that there is such a function $f$ defined on a neighbourhood $D$ of the origin. Define $g(z) = z^3$. For $n$ even, we see that $f(1/n) = g(1/n)$ and since $\{ 1/n \}$ has an accumulation point, the identity theorem implies that $f=g$ everywhere on $D$.

However, this contradicts that $f(1/n) = -1/n^3$ for odd $n$, and consequently $f$ can't exist.